# Changing Screen Views In Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've recently started learning Swift, and need help. The program was running fine before, but I dont know what I did and now it doesnt work, buttons dont appear and it crashes on one screen. an Error says "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyExeption', reason: [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not a key value coding-compliant for the key nextButton.' Ive got a button that you click to go to the next screen, but i click on it and it crashes. Heres the code on the HomeViewController, SecondScreenViewController, and ThirdScreenViewController.

HomeViewController

```
@IBAction func notifiyButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    print("Pressed")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewSegue", sender: self)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    print("View has loaded! ")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

SecondScreenViewController:

```
  @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!


@IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "whotoclass", sender: self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textField.delegate = self
    print("View 2 Loaded")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//Hide Keyboard when user touches outside keybaord
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//Presses return key
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return(true)
}
```

ThirdScreenViewController:

```
import UIKit
```

class ThirdScreenViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var joshClassButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func joshClassButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Also attached is the image of my Main.storyboard. Would be a massive help if anyone could assist here, as been working on problem for atleast 2 hours now. Thanks Everyone!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwhQt.png

Comment: You somehow unset the class of the second VC in the storyboard, so it's trying to load an ordinary `UIViewController`, which of course doesn't have a property called `nextButton`. Or, if you didn't unset the class, then you must have removed the `nextButton` outlet from your second VC.

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of the stack trace (the log's output above the exception)?

My gut instinct is to tell you to get away from storyboard and run; it's a bad tool that limits you in the long run. If you are set on using it, please include the stack trace and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Hey guys. thank you very very much for helping out. I mucked around and fixed it myself. found that i had deleted it but it was still in the code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try this for Swift 3

[image]

```
public func settingAction(_sender: UIButton) {
    let settingStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SettingViewController", bundle: nil)
    let settingVC = settingStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingViewController") as! SettingViewController
    self.present(settingVC, animated: true, completion: {

    })
}
```